# Missing Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization version 11

Tags: winforms, microsoft-reporting

I have a click once application that we have been working on.  The hosting server recently changed and a dependency on the Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll version 11 is now missing from the GAC.

I didn't realize this was there in the first place.  I would like to include this dependency in the application file and publishing, but I cannot seem to locate this as a NuGet pacakge.

I am not even sure this assembly is required as I don't see it being referenced anywhere - so my only guess is it is a transitive dependency.

Where is this assembly so I can include it with the application build.